# Fullcalendar How to display various days and hours

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a table with values: day, start, end. For example Monday 9:00-15:00 , Friday 12:00-16:00. And then I want render fullcalendar agendaweek with only days and time get from database(for example monday,friday). I'm using Symfony2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if I understand what you want to do here, you want something like this : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ (click on the "week" button) but that will only display days with events in them? so your week calendar will jump from monday to lets say Friday, then sunday and etc?

Comment: Adding events it possible only in days and time from database. I want display for example only Mondays from 9:00 to 15:00 and fridays from 12:00 to 16:00.